# In Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, how is Odo able shapshift his comm badge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

In *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, one of the characters, Odo is able to shape-shift into other forms, including his humanoid form. When he is in his humanoid form, he is able to form clothing. That makes sense, but what about the comm badge? That is technology and is fully functional. I don't remember that being explained in the series, so this bothers me. Other changelings also pulled this off, like when a changeling impersonated Dr Bashir for a while. To my understanding a changeling should not be able to produce technology when they change shape. But how is that possible?